# Why and how Zig programs behave differently when compiled in different modes?

Tags: compilation, zig

In [this section of a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgjRyaRTH6E&t=2070s) a scenario is shown that causes programs compiled with `ReleaseFast` behave differently than programs compiled with `Debug`.

Why is that the case? Shouldn't `Debug` mode go through extra steps to help developers understand their bugs? Here the opposite seems to be happening.

What else should I expect to differ between `Debug` and `ReleaseFast` modes?

Comment: That is a very long video, can you try to isolate what part specifically you refer to? Ideally extracting a code sample from it

Comment: Skipping through the video a bit I suspect you refer to the case where the `getMsg` function returns the address of a local variable. That is a general case of *undefined behavior* that is currently not handled by the Zig compiler: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/5725 - hopefully it will be addressed, but it's a case that can be difficult to detect properly (as per the comments on the issue)

Comment: I think I left the video in the correct position (or maybe my local YouTube page has that position stored and is tricking me?), but I should have left that clear.

Comment: No, it's saved locally for you. Links that point to a specific time usually have a parameter like `&t=300`, you can see an example in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I used the default procedure to share the video with the specific time and YouTube gave me that URL and it seemed to be working, so I thought something had changed -- turns out YouTube was just tricking me. Anyway I've edited the question now to point to the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be referring to the [34:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgjRyaRTH6E&t=2070s)-36:00 moment in the video. It demonstrates illegal code that no one should write in the first place. As UnholySheep [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77273075/why-and-how-zig-programs-behave-differently-when-compiled-in-different-modes#comment136227756_77273075), this should be [caught](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/5725) by the safety checks in the future.

See the build mode [documentation](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Build-Mode). The main difference between [Debug](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Debug) and [ReleaseFast](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#ReleaseFast) is that ReleaseFast has optimizations enabled and [safety checks](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Undefined-Behavior) disabled. This means that in practice, code with undefined behavior may behave differently. This isn't a problem, because you [shouldn't write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Risks) code with undefined behavior in the first place.