# How do I run tests in `ReleaseFast` mode in Zig?

Tags: testing, compilation, zig

Given that compiling in `Debug` or `ReleaseFast` mode may [yield different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77273075/why-and-how-zig-programs-behave-differently-when-compiled-in-different-modes/77279198#77279198), I wanted to check if my library code works correctly and catch any bugs by using tests.

However, I couldn't find any option to tell tests to be compiled and run in `ReleaseFast` mode. I assume they are all running on `Debug` mode by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are exactly the same as if you were simply compiling the code.

Using the [build system](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Zig-Build-System):

`zig build test -Doptimize=ReleaseFast`

Without the build system:

`zig test ./test.zig -O ReleaseFast`

As a proof of concept, this fails in `Debug`, but works in `ReleaseFast`:

```
test "should fail in debug" {
    var a = [3]u8{ 1, 2, 3 };
    var b: []u8 = a[0..2];
    var i: usize = 2;

    try std.testing.expect(b[i] == 3);
}
```

And here is one that fails in `ReleaseFast` but works in `Debug`:

```
fn getString() []u8 {
    var s: [32]u8 = undefined;
    s[0] = 'h';
    s[1] = 'e';
    s[2] = 'l';
    s[3] = 'o';
    return s[0..4];
}

test "should fail in release" {
    var s = getString();

    try std.testing.expectEqual(s[0], 'h');
    try std.testing.expectEqual(s[1], 'e');
    try std.testing.expectEqual(s[2], 'l');
    try std.testing.expectEqual(s[3], 'o');
}
```